# python lxml unavailable in dev_appserver(gae,windows)

Tags: python, windows, google-app-engine, lxml

I have installed lxml yet.

It works fine in IDLE.

But when I start an basic app described below with dev_appserver.py ,server returns error "No module named lxml".

```
import webapp2,lxml

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("test")
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([("/(.*)", MainPage)],debug=True)
```

How can I resolve this??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumingly you're using Python 2.7 runtime. This runtime provides a fine way for configuring libraries.

Please add libraries section in your app.yaml as follows:

```
libraries:
- name: lxml
  version: latest
```

For more details, please see:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/using27#Configuring_Libraries

Answer (score 0):

Any python library you use will need to be in your app folder - otherwise, it won't work when deployed, because only your app folder is deployed to App Engine.  You'll need to put a copy of lxml in your app folder.

Secondly though, I don't think lxml will work at out, since it runs on top of C libraries, and only pure python projects work on App Engine.

Comment: lxml support is provided by AppEngine: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#lxml